# What is an "expire date" for Ukrainian internal passport?

Tags: passports

I thought it has no expiration date, but some online payment systems (payoneer) require it.

Comment: If it has no expiration date you might try entering 31 December 9999 as a workaround, or whatever other maximum date value the system will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old Ukrainian internal passports (a passport book style) have the kind of expiration date stated in the law until you reach 45. Notably the passport which was not properly endorsed by authorities at your 25th and 45th birthday [is considered invalid](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8). This could be considered its expiration date.

After you reach 45, the passport is valid as long as you're alive. If this is your case, you need to reach out to the Payoneer support and ask what you should type. I would not put some "sufficiently high" number there as it might be considered providing incorrect information, which might possibly result in account suspension or termination - payment system processors are often quite paranoid.

The new Ukrainian ID has the expiration date stated on it.